# Duplicated not returning expected result

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say the below `df`

```
df <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3)
                , datee = as.Date(c('2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'))
                ); df

   id      datee
1:  1 2022-01-01
2:  2 2022-01-02
3:  2 2022-01-02
4:  3 2022-01-03
```

and I wanted to keep only the non-duplicated rows

```
df[!duplicated(id, datee)]

    id      datee
1:  1 2022-01-01
2:  2 2022-01-02
3:  3 2022-01-03
```

which worked.
However, with the below `df_1`

```
df_1 <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2)
                 , b = c(1,1,3)
                 ); df_1
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 1 1
3: 2 3
```

using the same method does not rid the duplicated rows

```
df_1[!duplicated(a, b)]

   a b
1: 1 1
2: 1 1
3: 2 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you'll need: `unique(df_1, by = c('a','b'))`, or `df_1[!duplicated(df_1, by = c('a', 'b'))]`, or set keys first: `setkey(df_1, a, b); df_1[!duplicated(df_1)]`

Comment: @Wimpel
I was aware of `unique` tho wanted to find out why `duplicated` was not working (bugging me). Thank you.

`df_1[!duplicated(df_1, by = c("a", "b"))]` worked. But the syntax differs to `df[!duplicated(id, datee)]`. Why is this?

Also, thanks for the tip on setkey. I don't use (prefer) it much as I like to have it dynamic. Thank you, tho

Comment: Actually, your first try is also problematic.  Just change the third row as   **2022-01-03**. It makes all the rows different from each other. 
`df <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3), datee = as.Date(c('2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03')))` . However `df[!duplicated(id, datee)]` removes the third row. That is a mistake as well.  The right syntax should be `df[!duplicated(df)]` or `df_1[!duplicated(df_1)]`.

Comment: @maydin you are correct. I ought to have substituted more dummy values in my testing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's dive in to why your `df_1[!duplicated(a, b)]` doesn't work.

`duplicated` uses S3 method dispatch.

```r
library(data.table)

.S3methods("duplicated")
# [1] duplicated.array           duplicated.data.frame     
# [3] duplicated.data.table*     duplicated.default        
# [5] duplicated.matrix          duplicated.numeric_version
# [7] duplicated.POSIXlt         duplicated.warnings       
# see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Looking at those, we aren't using `duplicated.data.table` since we're calling it with individual vectors (it has no idea it is being called from within a `data.table` context), so it makes sense to look into `duplicated.default`.

```r
> debugonce(duplicated.default)
> df_1[!duplicated(a, b)]
debugging in: duplicated.default(a, b)
debug: .Internal(duplicated(x, incomparables, fromLast, if (is.factor(x)) min(length(x), 
    nlevels(x) + 1L) else nmax))
Browse[2]> match.call()                           # ~ "how this function was called"
duplicated.default(x = a, incomparables = b)
```

Confirming with `?duplicated`:

```
       x: a vector or a data frame or an array or 'NULL'.

incomparables: a vector of values that cannot be compared.  'FALSE' is
          a special value, meaning that all values can be compared, and
          may be the only value accepted for methods other than the
          default.  It will be coerced internally to the same type as
          'x'.
```

From this we can see that `a` is being used for deduplication, and `b` is used as "incomparable". Because `b` contains the value `1` that is in `a` and duplicated, then rows where `a==1` are not tested for duplication.

To confirm, if we change `b` such that it does not share (duplicated) values with `a`, we see that the deduplication of `a` works as intended (though it is silently ignoring `b`'s dupes due to the argument problem):

```r
df_1 <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2) , b = c(2,2,4))
df_1[!duplicated(a, b)]                  # accidentally correct, `b` is not used
#        a     b
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     2     4
unique(df_1, by = c("a", "b"))
#        a     b
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     2     4


df_2 <- data.table(a = c(1,1,2) , b = c(2,3,4))
df_2[!duplicated(a, b)]                  # wrong, `b` is not considered
#        a     b
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     2     4
unique(df_2, by = c("a", "b"))
#        a     b
#    <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     1     3
# 3:     2     4
```

(Note that `unique` above is actually `data.table:::unique.data.table`, another S3 method dispatch provided by the `data.table` package.)

`debug` and `debugonce` are your friends :-)

Comment: Step by step troubleshooting. Very logical.
Learned the below from your answer: `.S3methods()`, `debugonce()`.
To summarise. Since `base` and `data.table` have the same function (name), the class of inputs (in this case) determined which got called.
In hindsight, I should have substituted more dummy data in my testing as you and @maydin pointed out.

Huge thank you for your time!
p.s. Happy New Year !

Comment: Yes, S3 dispatch is based on the class of its first argument. Even if an object inherits multiple classes (e.g., `c("data.table", "data.frame")`), when doing method-dispatch, `fun.classname` is searched for each of the classes until one is found. If none found, then `fun.default` is used. (This assumes that `fun` is defined using `UseMethod("fun")`. This comment is not meant to be a tutorial on S3.) BTW, `data.table` doesn't export its S3 method, but it defines `data.table:::duplicated.data.table`, which is found after `library(data.table)` because `base::duplicated` is already defined there.

Comment: Clarification: `base` defines `duplicated` (main function, calls `UseMethod("duplicated")`) and `duplicate.default` (among others).

Comment: What did you mean by "data.table doesn't export its S3 method"?
Also, instead of bothering you too much. Any page you recommend me reading?

Thank you

Comment: I mean that normally S3 methods are declared, but if you have function-completion (RStudio and emacs/ess have this) and type in `duplicated<tab><tab>`, you are unlikely to see `duplicated.data.table`, but my the fact that it was defined as an S3 method and attached to the search path, it will be found nonetheless. @SweepyDodo

Comment: Further info: reading `?.S3methods`, you'll find *"The S3 method name is followed by an asterisk '\*' if the method definition is not exported from the package namespace in which the method is defined"*. (And note the output from the call at the top of my answer.)